# What is the purpose of these two connectors on this motherboard? What can connect to them?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan, hp-pavilion, minipci

I have been in the process of upgrading my computer. While adding more electronic parts to it, I came across these two types of connectors on the motherboard (HP N-Alvorix-RS880-uATX) and I am not sure what actually can be connected to them. I have searched on HP's website for detailed information, yet have not come across anything that might be able to identify what can be connected into these types of connectors. The connectors I am looking to identify are circled in red on the pictures provided. One is some sort of J9 3 Pin connector, and another is a tiny 4 pin connector by the PCIe Mini slot. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those connectors are 3 pin fan connectors. See the image below:

[image]

You are not required to plug anything into them. Many motherboards give you more than you need. While not required, in order for your motherboard to ever control the fan speed, the ones on the motherboard need to be used. If this is not a requirement to you then you can plug it into the power supply or elsewhere. FYI the red and black are the power, and the yellow wire is the PWM wire.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for replying so quickly! I am super OCD and decided to make complete use of the motherboard by using all connections. One final question, the four pin slot near the PCIe mini slot at the very top of the picture is also a fan connector?

Comment: Hmm. After looking around a little more, the 3 pin fan connector image posted does not seem to have the same form factor as the two pin connectors in the motherboard image. Maybe this is some sort of OEM pin connector instead? I tried to plug in a spare 3 pin fan and it does not fit due to the form factor. The pins are the same, but physically, it will not fit.

Comment: I would not be shocked that HP would use hardware that had non-standard fan connectors on it.  They also use non-standard power supplies.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I think that may be the case. There are also some strange cover plates underneath the internal fan that are considered OEM parts. Standard cover plates and pci cover brackets do not fit to size underneath there. I had to specifically find the HP product number to find it and order it. I really wish I could at least figure out the part number for these connectors.

Comment: It is highly likely if it is just two pins that those are a 5v and Ground, neglecting the yellow PWM one. You could verify with a multimeter

Comment: Both of the connectors are a three pin and four pin respectively. I'm sure it may just be some sort of HP OEM connector. I'll have to search around for a model number or something. Either way, thanks for attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: You should try with a multimeter to be sure though. Typically if there are 4, the pins are for 5v and 12v in pairs. Not a problem :)